# How to minimize all SQL stored procedures at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

My question is not quite a programming question, more along the line of how to use the software. Well, I have a file that contains all of my stored procedures for a webpage (approximately 100 stored procedures). When I open the the file I minimize the stored procedures so the file is easier to sift through. I was wondering if there was any way to minimize all of the stored procedures all at once.

I know that in Visual Studio you can highlight all of the code the press CNTRL+M+M and it will minimize all of the functions. Anything similar to this in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the menu:

`Edit` -> `Outlining` -> `Toggle All Outlining`

To create your own keyboard shortcut, again from the menu `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment` -> `Keyboard`, select the command `Edit.ToggleAllOutlining` and create a new shortcut of your choice in `Global` or `SQL Query editor`.

Comment: Hey! Awesome! I have been looking for forever how to do this. Thank you!!! I can accept an snwer in 11 minutes

Comment: You can also assign your own keyboard shortcut if you need.

Comment: And how would I go about that?

Comment: I've used "Toggle All Outlining" for quite a while in SSMS 2008R2/2012. I invoke it with ALT + E + O + L

Comment: @DMason Do you mean `ALT` and not `CTRL`? That effectively presses the menu item.

Comment: @DavidG:  Yes!  Thx for catching that.  Comment fixed.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Collapses all outlining regions to show just the outermost groups in the hierarchy
CTRL+M, CTRL+A

Found this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx

Comment: I think this is only in SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Tested it in SSMS 2012 a minute ago. Worked like a charm.
Although- it only collapses, does not expand code.

Comment: Perhaps it's some patch which added such functionality in later version? I cannot think of anything else. I don't recall creating such shortcut in my SSMS.